Polygon from Periodic Tiling
Mathematica has a set of periodic tilings
periodictilings = Entity["PeriodicTiling"] // EntityList

Say I take one
Entity["PeriodicTiling", "ChevronTiling"][EntityProperty["PeriodicTiling", "PrimitiveUnit"]]


How can I get this shape as a Polygon?
If you click on the cell and go "Convert to Input Form", I can manually select the polygon:
Polygon[{{0, 1/2}, {0, 3/2}, {1, 1}, {2, 3/2}, {2, 1/2}, {1, 0}}]

But this is, of course, very manual - is there a programmatic way of doing so?

Entity["PeriodicTiling", "ChevronTiling"][
 EntityProperty["PeriodicTiling", "PrimitiveUnit"]]
Cases[%, _Polygon, All]


{Polygon[Number of points: 6 Embedding dimension: 2]}


Unfortunately, this is not the required Polygon[{{0, 1/2}, {0, 3/2}, {1, 1}, {2, 3/2},          {2, 1/2}, {1, 0}}]}, {2, 1}],

To get the coordinates of the vertices of a polygon, you apply: PolygonCoordinates. E.g.: PolygonCoordinates[Polygon[...]]

@DanielHuber: Unfortunately, PolygonCoordinates[Cases[%, _Polygon, All][[1]]] results in {{0,1/2},{0,3/2},{1,0},{1,1},{2,1/2},{2,3/2}}, not in {0, 1/2}, {0, 3/2}, {1, 1}, {2, 3/2},          {2, 1/2}, {1, 0}}]}, {2, 1}] and a self-intersected polygon is obtained.

@DanielHuber Coordinates in exact same ordering can be retrieved by Polygon[...][[1]]. PolygonCoordinates returns coordinates in  form of CanonicalizePolygon. Which may be in different order then in the original polygon.

@DanielHuber: The code you suggested Entity["PeriodicTiling", "ChevronTiling"][   EntityProperty["PeriodicTiling", "PrimitiveUnit"]]; PolygonCoordinates[Cases[%, _Polygon, All]] returns "PolygonCoordinates::reg: {Polygon[Number of points: 6 Embedding dimension: 2 ]} is not a correctly specified region.".

I removed some comments that I didn't think were constructive. The comment that PolygonCoordinates returns a self-intersecting polygon appears to be correct, and the explanation with CanonicalizePolygon explains what the issue is. This looks like a meaningful exchange to me.

@user64494 Regarding the last comment about "is not a correctly specified region": Cases returns a list containing a polygon and the error comes from applying PolygonCoordinates on the list rather than on the polygon.

@C.E. The non-meaningful exchange is that the user user64494 is unable to use the code properly and is instead blaming the flawless answer rather than acknowledging their own inability to understand it.

pts = Entity["PeriodicTiling", "ChevronTiling"][
      EntityProperty["PeriodicTiling", "PrimitiveUnit"]] // 
     Cases[#, Polygon[a_], All] & // MeshPrimitives[First@#, 0] & // 
   Map[Apply[Sequence]] // Rationalize


{{0, 1/2}, {1, 0}, {2, 1/2}, {2, 3/2}, {1, 1}, {0, 3/2}}

SimplePolygonQ@Polygon@pts


True


Why doing all unnecessary steps when Polygon[...][[1]] do the job if you want the coordinates?

PolygonCoordinates and MeshPrimitives[#,0]& do not produce the same result. So this is not assuming anything about the polygon. In this particular case, it would be the same result.

I am not saying they produce the same result. OP wanted the original polygon from Entity. If you want also the original coordinates in original ordering then Polygon[...][[1]] is enough. No need to use anything else. In what should be the coordinates form MeshPrimitives better than from Polygon[...][[1]]?

Suppose the output of Entity would be a self-intersecting polygon. If you apply your code to it it would produce a non-self-intersecting polygon. I.e. not what OP asked for. OP wanted exactly the same polygon as in the output of Entity.

You have to ask the OP what they intended. Everyone is free to ever so slightly interpret.

I think OP question is clear "How can I get this shape as a Polygon?". The discussion about coordinates started by incompetent comments by user user64494 who is not able to use the code properly. I guess this is what you was influenced by. But anyway I do not consider your answer as being bad.
